PHP 7 and same name for method and class
I was writing a simple hello world class with PHP, it prints Hello World twice while what I expected is it prints Hello World once.
I discovered that to obtain a correct behaviour I have to add _contruct and _destruct to the HelloWorld class. Why?
class HelloWorld
{
    public function text() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public function helloWorld() {
        echo $this->text();
    }
}

$helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
$helloWorld->helloWorld();


If you enable warnings it'll tell you why. In PHP 7 methods that have the same name as the class are constructors.

Demo with deprecation notice: https://3v4l.org/a8JYT#v7.4.33

I understood, thank you. It's a bit of time I don't use PHP, as I can understand case sensitivity is not considered in PHP 7, is it right?

No PHP is case sensitive so $x is not the same as $X and function text() is different to function Text()

BIG NOTE PHP 7.anything is now well out of date. Upgrade your PHP to PHP8.3 at least! See Supported Versions

@RiggsFolly you say PHP is case sensitive but why helloWorld is treated as HelloWorld (same name) in the class I wrote?

Functions, methods and class names are case insensitive. Just another case of PHP being PHP.

Until PHP 7.x, if a class did not have a __construct() method, a method named after the class itself functioned as the constructor (which I find illogical). From PHP 7.x onwards, this behavior was deprecated, and as of PHP 8.x, it has been completely removed.

Old-style constructors: Prior to PHP 8.0.0, classes in the global
namespace will interpret a method named the same as the class as an
old-style constructor. That syntax is deprecated, and will result in
an E_DEPRECATED error but still call that function as a constructor.
If both __construct() and a same-name method are defined,
__construct() will be called.
In namespaced classes, or any class as of PHP 8.0.0, a method named
the same as the class never has any special meaning.
Always use __construct() in new code.

Source: Constructors and Destructors


PHP 4 style constructors (methods that have the same name as the class they are defined in) are deprecated, and will be removed in the future. PHP 7 will emit E_DEPRECATED if a PHP 4 constructor is the only constructor defined within a class. Classes that implement a __construct() method are unaffected.
class foo {
    function foo() {
        echo 'I am the constructor';
    }
}


Source: Deprecated features in PHP 7.0.x

Since you are using a version of PHP prior to 8.x, the helloWorld() method was executed both during the class declaration (as it acted as a constructor) and later when explicitly called by you. This explains why the output appeared twice. From PHP 8.x onward, this behavior is removed, and such methods are no longer treated as constructors.
If you add a __construct() method (even if it's empty), it will become the primary constructor, and the helloWorld() method will no longer be executed during class declaration.
